# How to find which server in the DNS 'chain' is returning NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system

For almost 48 hours now we've been experiencing sporadic DNS outages for A and CNAME records. Have mostly been tracking the issue via ping and nslookup on Windows.

Lookups for 'www' (A), 'img1' (CNAME), 'store' (A) have come back as not found (windows ping or nslookup says it just cant find the host) - andon one online DNS tester I even saw an NXDOMAIN response.

I'm pretty sure that somewhere in the DNS 'chain' there is a cached NXDOMAIN response coming back thats still getting cached after 46 hours now.

I've even seen a case where - using nslookup - i've done a lookup on a CNAME record `img1.example.com` 10 times within 5 seconds and had negative and positive responses from the same verizon DNS server within a second.

Like I said this has happened for 48 hours now. The 'outage' occurs only briefly for a few minutes, but has been seen from at least 4 differnet geographical locations/networks.

I thought the bad record would have cleared itself out by now, but I'm hoping that finding the offending DNS server I can at least try to contact them - or find out whose fault it is.

Answers to obvious questions

- DNS currently godaddy, has not been changed at all
- domain has been active with DNS on godaddys hosted DNS (ns41.domaincontrol.com) for 3 years
- Problem observed on several differnet networks, verizon DSL, comcast cable, verizon EVDO, site24x7 website
- even happening with CNAME records to amazon A3 (i.e. 100% not a webserver problem and 100% DNS problem)
- I'm not an expert, but the problem confirmed by two people that know more than i do. one thinks the most likely issue is a cached NXDOMAIN response somewhere.

Should we just wait up to 4 days before changing DNS providers? 
Is there a tool of some sort to trace where the DNS is coming from and find the actual server which is caching the NXDOMAIN response - or perhaps a service to just test hundreds/thousands of DNS servers for their responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have a conceptual issue with how DNS works.

Only DNS servers performing recursive resolution cache lookups. The DNS servers that the affected users on "verizon DSL, comcast cable, verizon EVDO, site24x7 website" are using are the ones caching lookups.

The root DNS servers, .com servers, and the servers authoritative for your domain aren't caching lookups, because they're not providing recursive resolution service.

It's possible (likely, actually, from what I'm seeing in Google searches) that GoDaddy is sporadically returning NXDOMAINs for your domain, and those NXDOMAINs are being cached by recursive resolvers. (Per [RFC2308](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2308.html), they should be cached, at most, either the TTL for the zone as specified in the SOA, or the SOA minimum-- whichever is least.)

Apparently, GoDaddy's "free" DNS service isn't too highly regarded. I don't use it, personally, so I can't comment on it.

There is no central "list" of DNS servers providing recursive resolution for you to "test against". (I have one here in my house, and I could spin a few more up on VMs if I needed to...) You need a reliable provider to be authoritative for your domain, and you just have to hope that everybody else in the world honors TTLs and acts as "good DNS citizens".

---

Edit:

"Recursive resolution" is the process by which the a DNS server resolves a record for which it is not authoritative. The process starts with the root DNS servers, and proceeds recursively (that is, a process that loops back on itself) through all the authoritative DNS servers for the domains specified in the query until the last DNS server is reached and the desired resource record (or a negative response) is returned.

For a three-level query, like "www.example.com", the following occurs (I am leaving out the fact that, all along the way, the ISP DNS server is checking its cache in lieu of issuing queries to remote DNS servers and putting the results it receives into its cache, to make this clearer and a bit more simplistic):

- Your PC issues a query to your specified DNS server (at your ISP, for example).
- The ISP DNS server verifies that it doesn't have a response in cache, and then queries one of the root DNS servers.
- The root DNS server, only being authoritative for the root, responds with a list of DNS servers authoritative for the gTLD specified in the query (.com, .net, .tv, .fu, etc). The protocol continues as such, w/ the full query always being sent to each successive DNS server throughout this process. Since it's not possible to know which DNS server will be authoritative for any given query and we want to minimize the number of round-trips, we always send the full domain in each query.
- The ISP DNS server queries one of the DNS servers returned as authoritative for the gTLD specified.
- The gTLD DNS server, being authoritative for the second-level domain (example, microsoft.com, example.com, etc) only, responds with a list of DNS servers authoritative for the second-level domain.
- The ISP DNS server queries one of the DNS servers returned as authoritative for the second-level domain.
- The DNS server authoritative for the second-level, being for the third-level domain (www.microsoft.com, ftp.example.com, etc), domain returns the record requested.
- The ISP DNS server returns the record your PC queried back to your PC.

Typically ISPs offer recursive resolution services to their Customers. The DNS servers at hosting providers that are authoritative for Customer hosted domains generally don't provide recursive service (and will return the root servers if queried for domains they aren't authoritative for).

Comment: we're using godaddy's DNS as part of a dedicated server plan. whether its FREE or not i guess is irrelevant from what you're saying. if they really are returning NXDOMAIN then they are the weakest link and changing providers will fix the issue. we've only seen this in last 48 hours though and not before - and its real users seeing it. we have constant traffic coming to the site so caching rate should be very high. i'm not quite clear what you mean about recursive DNS. theres obviously some kind of chain of caching - my PC, my router, verizon DNS, etc.. should i raise my TTL ?

Comment: So most likely the GoDaddy name servers haven't replicated the domain properly amongst themselves. What is the domain?

Comment: rollingrazor.com - its been up for over a year on that DNS provider. the oddest behavior i saw earlier today was on DNS server 68.238.64.12 (local ISP) performing multiple lookups. i got NXDOMAIN then the correct CNAME resolution and then NXDOMAIN again within 10 seconds. problem fixes itself and then several hours later resolves incorrectly again

Comment: Jeff Atwood and the Stack Overflow crew didn't like GoDaddy's DNS service much: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/  Personally, I use the provider that Jeff went with, Dynamic Network Services: http://dynamicnetworkservices.com/

Comment: sounds like a load balanced server where one of the servers has expired the zone

Comment: no easy way to find out where though? not that knowing would do us much good, but would at least perhaps indicate to us how widespread the problem may be. all the (known) locations where we had issues were for machines within Los Angeles. i'm up for switching DNS provider for sure - but don't want to cause other possible issues - and have other more pressing priorities. i see no reason why this shouldnt 'fix itself' and would be surprised if it is going to keep occuring considering nobody else is tweeting about the same issue right now. should i increase TTL for A records as a safeguard?

Comment: irony is i actually kind of remember jeff+joel talking about this on the podcast months ago. i may even have read this article before. lol. i think we'll definitely switch

Comment: @greeblesnort: That's what I'd say, too. Here's somebody else's experience that seems to confirm: https://lists.dns-oarc.net/pipermail/dns-operations/2009-March/003612.html

Comment: @evan that last link sounds exactly like what we've been experiencing. now to tell the boss that it could still take another 48hours to disappear even if we switch :-)

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it but the servers that are authorative for the root domain (.) are technically the only "root" servers (a.root-servers.net, b.root-servers.net, etc.). The servers responsible for the gTLD's (.com, .edu, etc.) are not technically root servers as they don't exist at the root. These servers (a.gtld-servers.net, b.gtld-servers.net, etc.) exist one level below the root servers in the DNS hierarchy.

Comment: @evan - one small error in your explanation of recursive DNS - in fact the resolver sends the _whole_ question to each server in the chain, not just the bits it thinks the server knows about.  Hence if I'm trying to lookup www.fraggleblat.somejunk.tld then that whole query string gets to the root, not just the .tld bit.

Comment: @joeqwerty: There's one root because we all agree to use one root. That's not a physical limitation of the protocol, that's just humans agreeing how things should be.

Comment: @Alnitak: Quite right. In the interests of making things simple I took a bit too much liberty w/ my description. I'll drop and edit on and change that, since it's The Right Thing(tm)... >smile<

Comment: @Evan: I'm not clear on what you're saying (and I'm not trying to be argumentative, just trying to make sure my understanding of DNS is correct), but the servers responsible for the gTLD's are not root servers. When I think of the root servers (and when I look at my DNS server's list of root hints) I think of a.root-servers.net, etc. So a query from my DNS client (barring any caching) goes to my DNS server, then to one of the root servers (.), then to one of the gTLD servers (.com, etc.), then to the server that's authorative for the domain in question (example, etc). Am i wrong?

Comment: @Joeqwerty: That's what I'm saying in my description. The recursive resolver queries the root servers, which return a referral to the gTLD servers, which return a referral to the second-level servers, etc. I see words that could be confusing, so I'll drop an edit on and move them around.

Comment: @Evan, thanks and my apologies for any confusion on my part.

Comment: @joeqwerty: No worries or apologies necessary. I want my answers to be clear, concise (ha!), and most of all correct. If something isn't phrased well or is unclear then it needs fixed.

Comment: thx for the interesting discussion guys. switched over to DynDns at 1am friday pst. but still seen bad lookups throughout the day which i guess is to be expected - but still odd that at the same location its come up and down. dns records only in the new nameserver are resolving just fine and ones only on the old nameserver arent anymore. fingers crossed...

Answer (score 0):

You really need to address the root of the problem. This is what I would do:

1. Perform a whois query for the domain in question.
2. Write down the name servers listed for the domain.
3. Perform an NS nslookup against each of the name servers listed in whois and make sure they return the same list of name servers that whois listed.
4. Query each name server from step 2 for the domain in question and make sure they all return the correct info. If any of the name servers return an NXDOMAIN response then you've found the culprit.

Any name servers that are listed in whois that aren't listed when you query the name servers individually need to be removed from whois.

Conversely, any name servers returned from your NS nslookup that aren't listed in whois need to be removed as name servers.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using dig to do the querying, rather than nslookup. That aside, I've found enough complaints out there to make me think that GoDaddy has load-balancers on their DNS server such that you won't be able to find the errant DNS servers as they're hidden behind the load-balancers.

Comment: Don't think dig is available for Windows.

Comment: @fpmurphy dig is available for windows try a google search. It is certainly included as part of the BIND for windows software but requires a resolv.conf file to be created and a number of BIND dlls to be available.