# How do I do about managing a domain name using Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS services?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain

Okay, here's the deal. I have a server set up in my home that I want to use for a variety if things. It is running Windows Server 2k8 R2 with Active Directory Domain Services, Domain Controller, and DNS server roles installed. I bought a domain name from a Canadian domain registrar and I want to manage said domain using this server machine.

I have done a lot of Googling but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. What I want to do is somehow forward all the domain stuff to this server so I can control the domain name as well as things like subdomains.

Do I just open the proper ports and set this server as the nameserver in the registrar's panel? I tried doing this and their panel gives me an error. If this is the proper way I can then take the ticket to their panel as to why it's giving me an error, but I want to make sure it's set up on my end first.

Also, I just want to make sure that the outside world will be able to go to that domain, so how does this work exactly? When they query the name does it go to the registrar then the registrar passes them to my nameserver?

I suppose I should note as well that my local domain (on the network) is mydomain.local, but the domain I want to actually route to the server is mydomain.com and mydomain.ca (can I pair these two or do I have to set everything up for both? [by everything I mean subdomains and the like])

If you need any more info let me know, hopefully though this gives you a good idea of what I have and need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could do with some [background on how the DNS system works](https://serverfault.com/questions/90932/how-to-find-which-server-in-the-dns-chain-is-returning-nxdomain/90941#90941). Have a look at that answer briefly.

You need, at minimum, two DNS servers to host the DNS for your Internet domain (to provide redundancy and to satisfy [IANA's requirement that there be at least two delegated DNS servers for the domain](http://www.iana.org/procedures/nameserver-requirements.html)). Hosting the DNS for your domain yourself on this single physical server probably isn't the best strategy for availability. If you're just playing around then it's probably not a big deal (except that you'll still have to satisfy the IANA requirement).

You're ultimately looking to set the DNS server delegation at the registrar for the affected domain names to the DNS servers you're hosting. The text of the error that the registrar's "control panel" is giving you would probably be helpful in telling you why the registrar is denying your attempt to change the DNS server delegation to your own machine.

You will also need to open UDP and TCP port 53 through your firewall to the DNS server machine as you suggest in your question.

The Microsoft DNS server can be the authoritative DNS server for an arbitrary number of domains, so you can host "mydomain.local" along side "mydomain.com" and "mydomain.ca". Records are not replicated between domains, though, so if you create a "sub1.mydomain.com" domain that will not cause a "sub1.mydomain.ca" domain to exist automatically. Any replication like that you'd need to work out yourself w/ scripts, etc.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I think I have to clarify my intentions a bit, maybe what I'm trying to do isn't what I'm wanting to do. My plan is to have a domain mydomain.com that i can distribute the subdomains myself, for mostly my own personal use (so things like redundancy aren't important). I wanted to use my domain controller at home to route traffic based on what subdomain is given. My current setup is one machine with a few vm's on it, so if I have mail hosted on my linux box, I wanted to route mail.mydomain.com to that server directly, and other such things, can I do this easily?

Comment: @Tylor: What you're talking about, in terms of "routing" traffic for hostnames in the "mydomain.com" domain to your home computers is just creating "A" records (MX records for email, etc) in the "mydomain.com" DNS zone hosted by your current DNS servers. No DNS server delegation would be necessary.

Comment: @Evan-Anderson The problem is that the servers will all be on the same internet facing ip, now if I were to say have 3 web servers, all wanting to be run on www.mydomain.com, web2.mydomain.com, and web3.mydomain.com would I just have to put each web server on a different port? I've noticed internally using DNS I can route subdomains to specific local IPs, and that's what I was hoping to do. Even if the windows server just caught the subdomain calls and routed them, that would be fine too, but I assumed I needed to make it a full name server to do this.

Comment: @Tylor: HTTP host headers can help you host multiple web sites on the same IP address sharing the same TCP port 80. Unfortunately, if you only have a single public IP address then you only have a single public IP address. DNS takes care of resolving hostnames to IP addresses, and any services you'll be hosting behind that same public IP will all have to resolve to that public IP. That means, in effect, you only have one set of TCP ports to host services from, and no amount of DNS haggling is going to give you more.